# Gravatar Image Still Not Loading Open Cart Admin

Tags: php, opencart

Hi I am trying to get my gravatar api working with my open cart admin/controller/common/header.php and my admin/view/template/common/header.tpl

Still not working gave it ago before that some one gave me advice on but now not working? So thought give it ago another way but nothing.

admin / controller/ header. php

This is just trimmed down version

```
<?php 
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
protected function index($get_gravatar) {

}

function get_gravatar( $email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array() ) {
$url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
$url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
$url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
if ( $img ) {
$url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
$url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
$url .= ' />';
}
return $url;
}
```

admin / view / template / common / header.tpl

```
<?php 
$email = $user_info['email']; // Not Working "Need it to pick up who ever logins"
$email = "your@rmail.com"; // Works
$default = "http://www.somewhere.com/homestar.jpg";
$size = 150;
?>
<li>
<a href="" class="text-center">
<img src="<?php echo $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?d=" . urlencode( $default ) . "&s=" . $size;; ?>" alt="" />
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: did you make the changes in `system/library/user.php` that i told you earlier?

Comment: yes did all that still not work thats why moving on to another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes for getting gravatar image in header.tpl

***Update `system/library/user.php` as below:***

After: `$this->username = $user_query->row['username'];`

Add: `$this->email = $user_query->row['email'];`

---

Before: `public function getUserName() {`

Add:

```
  public function getUserEmail() {
    return $this->email;
  }
```

---

***Update `admin/controller/common/header.php` as below:***

After: `$this->data['logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->user->getUserName());`

Add: `$this->data['email'] = $this->user->getUserEmail();`

---

***Update `admin/view/template/common/header.tpl` as below:***

`<div class="img-circle">
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php echo md5(strtolower(trim($email))); ?>">
</div>`

Please let me know the result of these changes.

**Note:** In opencart, you need to assign values to variables like: `$this->data['variable_name']` in controller files and use them template files like: `$variable_name`.

Comment: Error Notice: Undefined property: User::$useremail in /home/cws01/public_html/opencart1561/system/library/user.php on line 88 error here public function getUserEmail() {
return $this->useremail;
}
public function getUserEmail() {
return $this->useremail;}

Comment: did you define the function   `public function getUserEmail()` twice ?? No need to repeat the changes again in `system/library/user.php`. I just pasted it here also, so that someone else may find all together in one post.

Comment: in user there is a login and a registery with same one row

Comment: Please note the first post at top of page has been change you will see what I mean

Comment: Just add 4 lines of code in `system/library/user.php`, make sure you don't repeat the code. Update `admin/controller/common/header.php`   as mentioned above and not `admin/controller/header.php`. After updating those files update the file: `admin/view/template/common/header.tpl`.

Comment: Oh well nothing worked have to give it up work on it another time

Comment: It's working fine for me. i tested the code in fresh opencart setup.

Comment: what version? of open cart

Comment: I have got it showing on my menu on header but now on my header does not show on sidebar even though in header.

Comment: may be some css issue

Comment: I have go it to work just had to change useremail to email on all things

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an extension to your url => www.gravatar.com/avatar/far512q3tgfqwe**.jpg** for example, a quick google search and i came up with this url, check it for further info:
http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

Try this piece of code in your header.php to get the email of the current logged in user:

```
    $this->load->model('user/user');
    $email_data = $this->model_user_user->getUser($this->user->getId());
    $email = $email_data['email'];
```

if you want to get emails for all users it need to be handled differently.

Comment: yes but need it to work off to can work with my email on my users profile I am working with open cart1561

Comment: so to be clear, the problem is that you can not specify the emails, you do not know how to call them? And by users are you referring to your site clients(showing on backend) or to backend users that login to your account? Provide me this info so i can give you a correct answer.

Comment: yes trying to use the php gravatar for my admin / controller/ common/header.php just above but better of course that is just sample at the moment because can not get it working So I want my users that login to my back end admin be able to use there email for gravatar but working in opencart 1561

Comment: I added that to top of header.php in admin common controller. and this to my view file <div class="img-circle"> <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php echo md5(strtolower(trim($email))); ?>"> </div> still nothing very strange

Comment: if you want to call it directy as a variabel you need to add one more line of code $this->data['email'] = $email; to use it with echo. And please try with extension also.

Comment: All fixed thank you so much had to change useremail to email. in all areas